# How to render a line plot that changes based on my inputs and shows a color line for each line

Tags: r, shiny

I created this shiny app and now I would like to add a line plot to the app.
The data is in a .csv file

I am able to generate data in a table format and I want to include a line plot that is reactive to my inputs.

```
shelter <- read.csv("shelter.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Shelter,Year,Cat,Dog,Rabbit,Other
Pitt,2013,31,22,19,23
Pitt,2014,23,54,65,15
Pitt,2015,56,62,28,24
Pitt,2016,65,23,33,32
Pitt,2017,49,74,36,18
Phila,2013,11,32,26,35
Phila,2014,66,65,145,27
Phila,2015,69,64,121,18
Phila,2016,84,81,195,9
Phila,2017,79,35,96,7
Allen,2013,161,36,26,11
Allen,2014,24,97,84,21
Allen,2015,101,74,24,19
Allen,2016,254,74,112,3
Allen,2017,95,63,247,22
Harris,2013,78,60,168,17
Harris,2014,29,85,39,16
Harris,2015,201,75,245,7
Harris,2016,27,55,88,9
Harris,2017,65,46,71,11
Read,2013,94,95,68,20
Read,2014,98,91,94,19
Read,2015,125,73,203,21
Read,2016,87,101,119,5
Read,2017,148,98,149,6
York,2013,56,73,65,14
York,2014,61,74,95,7
York,2015,99,89,84,2
York,2016,121,120,84,11
York,2017,67,68,85,2

#Code:

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel('Animal Shelter Data:'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Shelter", label = h4("Select a Shelter:"),choices =shelter$Shelter),

      checkboxGroupInput("Category", label = h4("Category"), 
                     choices = list("Cat" , "Dog" , "Rabbit", "Other"),
                     selected = list("Cat" , "Dog" , "Rabbit", "Other")),

      checkboxGroupInput("Year", label = h4("Select Year(s)"),
                     choices = unique(shelter$Year),
                     selected = list('2013', '2014', '2015', '2016','2017'))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("shelterdata"),
      plotOutput("lineplot")
    )
  ) 
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$shelterdata <- renderTable({
    shelterfilter <- subset(shelter[shelter$Shelter == input$Shelter & shelter$Year %in% input$Year,])
    shelterfilter[c('Shelter', 'Year', input$Category)]
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like to render a line plot that changes based on my `input$Shelter`, `input$Category`, `input$Year` and shows a color line for each animal:

- x-axis = Year
- y-axis = number of animals

Answer (score 0):

This answer requires the `tidyr`, `magrittr` and `ggplot2` packages. This code can be placed inside the `server` function.

```
output$lineplot <- shiny::renderPlot({
  shelterfilter <- subset(shelter[shelter$Shelter == input$Shelter & shelter$Year %in% input$Year,]) %>% 
    tidyr::gather(key = "Animal",value = "Animal.Qty",-Shelter,-Year)
  ggplot(data = shelterfilter,aes(x = Year,y=Animal.Qty,color=Animal)) + 
    geom_line()
})
```